# Integration test with rest assured and basic auth with CSRF

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, csrf, rest-assured

I have a working Spring Boot with AngularJs app based on https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

I am using Basic Authentication and I would like to write an integration test for it. Currently, I always get a 403 status code with the message:

```
Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?
```

This is my test:

```
@Test
public void givenAdmin_deleteOfBookIsAllowed() {

    Response response = given().auth().preemptive().basic("admin", "admin").get("/api/user/");
    response.then().log().all();
    String sessionId = response.sessionId();
    String token = response.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN");

    Book book = Books.randomBook();
    bookRepository.save(book);

    given()
            .sessionId(sessionId)
            .cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token)
            .header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", token)
            .pathParam("id", book.getId().getId())
            .when().delete("/api/books/{id}")
            .then().statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT);
}
```

I am using a custom token repo per the tutorial:

```
 private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

This is the request/response from the first call:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=7020E58A8D6DC2C883FD5D6BD086512A; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=6c44ae09-73f9-4115-bbbf-b01773ec1b91; Path=/
X-Application-Context: application:staging:0
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 07:43:21 GMT

{
    "details": {
        "remoteAddress": "127.0.0.1",
        "sessionId": "7020E58A8D6DC2C883FD5D6BD086512A"
    },
    "authorities": [
        {
            "authority": "ROLE_ADMIN"
        },
        {
            "authority": "ROLE_USER"
        }
    ],
    "authenticated": true,
    "principal": {
        "password": null,
        "username": "admin",
        "authorities": [
            {
                "authority": "ROLE_ADMIN"
            },
            {
                "authority": "ROLE_USER"
            }
        ],
        "accountNonExpired": true,
        "accountNonLocked": true,
        "credentialsNonExpired": true,
        "enabled": true
    },
    "credentials": null,
    "name": "admin"
}
```

And from the second call:

```
Request method: DELETE
Request path:   http://localhost:64588/api/books/04ad6d12-9b59-4ade-9a8a-e45daccb1f61
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    id=04ad6d12-9b59-4ade-9a8a-e45daccb1f61
Multiparts:     <none>
Headers:        X-XSRF-TOKEN=6c44ae09-73f9-4115-bbbf-b01773ec1b91
                Accept=*/*
Cookies:        JSESSIONID=7020E58A8D6DC2C883FD5D6BD086512A
                XSRF-TOKEN=6c44ae09-73f9-4115-bbbf-b01773ec1b91
Body:           <none>

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 07:44:21 GMT

{
    "timestamp": "2016-01-08T07:44:21.963+0000",
    "status": 403,
    "error": "Forbidden",
    "message": "Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?",
    "path": "/api/books/04ad6d12-9b59-4ade-9a8a-e45daccb1f61"
}
```

Comment: you can disable CSRF if you want

Comment: I know, but I don't want to disable it.

Comment: So, did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do 2 `GET` before post to use spring security `CSRF` protection in your rest client or integration test.

1. Make a `GET` request to login. This will return the `JSESSIONID` token and `XSRF-TOKEN` tokens. If you use the returned `XSRF-TOKEN` to `POST` it will fail, because we got it using empty/false `JSESSIONID`.
2. Get a useful `XSRF-TOKEN` from the second `GET`, using `JSESSIONID` from previous request.
3. Now you can use `XSRF-TOKEN` for your `POST`.

Example integration test for rest assured with basic auth and `CSRF` protection:

```
//1) get sessionId
Response response =
        given().auth().preemptive().basic(userName, userPassword).contentType(JSON).
        when().get(PREFIX_URL + "/user").
        then().log().all().extract().response();
String jsessionidId =  response.getSessionId();//or response.cookie("JSESSIONID");

//2) get XSRF-TOKEN using new/real sessionId
response =
        given().
        sessionId(jsessionidId).//or cookie("JSESSIONID", jsessionidId).
        contentType(JSON).
        when().get(PREFIX_URL + "/user").
        then().log().all().extract().response();

//3) post data using XSRF-TOKEN
given().log().all().
        sessionId(jsessionidId).//or cookie("JSESSIONID", jsessionidId).
        header("X-XSRF-TOKEN", response.cookie("XSRF-TOKEN")).
        queryParam("param",paramValue)).
        body(someData).
        contentType(JSON).
when().
        post(PREFIX_URL + "/post_some_data").
then().
    log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```